# How do I find files on a folder matching the first X characters on their filename, X being a number of my choice, on terminal or GUI, in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, duplicate-files

I searched the web for this and found a code on [a question in stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617065/find-duplicate-files-based-on-first-few-characters-of-filename) that was hailed as a solution to this. However, when I run in terminal, the output is this:

```
*Possible Dupes
Which dupe would you like to delete?
Enter # to delete or q to quit
#
./3: line 36: [: #: integer expression expected
./3: line 36: [: #: integer expression expected
./3: line 43: #: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "#")*
```

How can I know which dupe "would I like to delete" if I don't have a list of them? So, no solution at all to me. I'm at a loss on what to do. Oh, and "go read some manuals" is not helping.

I have 3255 files to sift through, and rather than spending hours looking at each file from A to Z, I don't want to find if a specific duplicate exists, I want to find if ANY filename repeats itself in the first X (can be 1,2 or more) characters so I can delete them, be it Bubble Bobble or Caesar or Pinball Dreams or whatever. I want to find WHICH files from those 3255 files from A to Z repeat themselves in the first characters, with me specifying how many characters I want to find.

I don't want to rename anything.

Examples of filenames:

```
Perfect General The (1991)(Ubisoft Entertainment).7z
Boulderdash 2 (1985)(First Star Software).7z
Bridge 7.0 (1992)(Artworx).7z
```

Expected output:

```
Bubble Bobble (1987)(Taito Corporation).7z
Bubble Bobble (1990)(Taito Corporation).7z
```

I don't want the code to delete anything, I just to want it to find the relevant files for me.

Code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    declare -a names
    
    xIFS="${IFS}"
    IFS="^M"
    
    while true; do
    awk -F'[-_ ]' '
        NR==FNR {seen[tolower($1)]++; next}
        seen[tolower($1)] > 1
    ' <(printf "%s\n" *.jar) <(printf "%s\n" *.jar) > tmp.dat
    
            IDX=0
            names=()
    
    
            readarray names < tmp.dat
    
            size=${#names[@]}
    
            clear
            printf '\nPossible Dupes\n'
    
            for (( i=0; i<${size}; i++)); do
                    printf '%s\t%s' ${i} ${names[i]}
            done
    
            printf '\nWhich dupe would you like to delete?\nEnter # to delete or q to quit\n'
            read n
    
            if [ $n == 'q' ]; then
                    exit
            fi
    
            if [ $n -lt 0 ] || [ $n -gt $size ]; then
                    read -p "Invalid Option: present [ENTER] to try again" dummyvar
                    continue
            fi
    
            #clean the carriage return \n from the name
            IFS='^M'
            read -ra TARGET <<< "${names[$n]}"
            unset IFS
    
            # now remove the filename sans any carriage returns
            # from the filesystem
            # 12/18/2020
            rm "${TARGET[*]}" 
            echo "removed ${TARGET[0]}" >> rm.log
    done
    
    IFS="${xIFS}"
```

Comment: MC doesn't do it for me. I want this to be automated, and I want the output to be on a text file.

Comment: Does something like `find /path/to/dir -type f -name "123*"` work for you? ... where `123` is your desired x prefix ... you should keep the glob `*`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the prompt. When it says `Enter # to delete`, it means enter the *number of the entry* that you want to delete, not that you enter a literal `#` character.

Comment: ... and in that case the error you get is normal when an arithmetic operator like e.g. `-lt` as it expects an integer indeed and not a string ... And please clarify whether you want to find certain files by name prefix like your question title describes or you want to delete duplicates or something else.

Comment: I don't think I explained myself well enough. I have 3255 files to sift through, and rather than spending hours looking at each file from A to Z, I don't want to find if a specific duplicate exists, I want to find if ANY filename repeats itself in the first X (can be 1,2 or more) characters so I can delete them, be it Bubble Bobble or Caesar or Pinball Dreams or whatever. How would I know which entry to delete if I don't have a list of the duplicates?!

Comment: Then simply use `printf '%s\n' Bubble*` (case sensitive)  ... BTW, the linked solutions will process files that have `-` or `_` in their names and having the extension `jar`  ... is that the case in your filenames?

Comment: They look like this: 
Perfect General The (1991)(Ubisoft Entertainment).7z
Boulderdash 2 (1985)(First Star Software).7z
Bridge 7.0 (1992)(Artworx).7z

Comment: I don't want to find if Bubble Bobble repeats itself in the first characters...I want to find WHICH files from those 3255 files from A to Z repeat themselves in the first characters, with me specifying how many characters I want to find.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us the _exact_ code you used, if you want us to help you fix this error (although muru already told you the issue there) or ii) show us a few of your file names and then what output you would expect from that example. Please don't answer in comments, add the information to the question where it can be properly formatted and will be visible to all.

Comment: One-liner, modified from your linked post `awk 'NR==FNR {seen[tolower(substr($0,1,6))]++; next} seen[tolower(substr($0,1,6))] > 1' <(printf "%s\n" *) <(printf "%s\n" *)` for first 6 characters ... Change **both** `6` and the other `6` (they must be equal) to change the number of prefix characters matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bash, you can add this shell function:

```bash
dupfind () 
{ 
    for f in *;
    do
        [[ "${p[@]}" =~ "Place_Holder${f:0:$1}" ]] && p+=("Dup_Place_Holder${f::$1}") || p+=("Place_Holder${f::$1}");
    done;
    for f in *;
    do
        [[ "${p[@]}" =~ "Dup_Place_Holder${f:0:$1}" ]] && echo "$f";
    done;
    unset p
}
```

... and use it for example to match the first six characters by calling its name `dupfind` and passing `6` to it like in this example:

```
$ dupfind 6
myfile111.txt
myfile1.txt
myfile2.txt
myfile31.txt
myfile32.txt
myfile-3.txt
myfile3.txt
$
$
$ LC_ALL=en_US ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:23 1myfile.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:23 2myfile.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:23 3myfile.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:23 4myfile.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:07 myfile-3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 14:58 myfile1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:23 myfile111.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 14:58 myfile2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 14:58 myfile3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:23 myfile31.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:23 myfile32.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:45 ss2mdgt.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:44 sssmdgt.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 11 15:44 sssmnbggt.txt
```

Or modifying a bit the AWK script from your linked post, you can do:

```
awk -v n=6 '
NR == FNR {
        seen[substr($0, 1, n)]++
        next
}

seen[substr($0, 1, n)] > 1 {
        print
}
' <(printf "%s\n" *) <(printf "%s\n" *)
```

... where `n=6` is the number of prefix characters to match.

**Notice** the AWK solution, although faster, will fail on filenames with newline character(s) in them while the shell function wont.

**However** GNU AWK (*not sure about the other implementations*) does support setting the record separator to a NULL character which makes it possible to handle such filenames if used like so:

```
awk -v n=6 '
BEGIN {
    RS = "\000"
}

NR == FNR {
        seen[substr($0, 1, n)]++
        next
}

seen[substr($0, 1, n)] > 1 {
        print
}
' <(printf "%s\0" *) <(printf "%s\0" *)
```

Comment: The modified AWK finally did what I wanted. Thank you.